# How to replace values in array numpy using np.where for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that contains a number of different labels and I would like to change the labels to something different.

Where, `original = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]`

And I want to change each values with, `modified = [1,3,8]`

so the output would look be `original_modified = [1,1,1,3,3,3,8,8,8,8]`

So far what I have done is this for loop below:

```
for x, y in zip(np.unique(original), modified):
    original_modified = np.where(original == x, original, y)
```

However, I am not getting the intended results as the output is incorrect, and I'm not quite sure as to why.

I understand I could get a way with a simple for loop with if conditions however, I am not sure if this would be a very dynamic solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `np.unique`, as it sorts the values. In this specific example, it works (`original` is ordered), but in general it doesn't. Try with `[2,2,2,10,10,10,0,0,0]` and `[1,3,8]`. Also, `np.unique()` is relatively slow (because it sorts).

Comment: Are the labels always numbers like `1,2,3`?  consecutive integers?  If you have arrays instead of lists, can you use `original` as indices:  `modified[original-1]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems in your code.

1. In your loop, you should read from `original_modified` instead of starting from `original` again at each iteration.
2. You reversed the last two arguments to `np.where()`.

This code works:

```
original_modified = original
for x, y in zip(np.unique(original), modified):
    original_modified = np.where(original == x, y, original_modified)
```

PS: As @PierreD pointed out, `np.unique()` might not be the right choice, since it sorts its results. If you need to preserve the order in which elements first appear in `original`, use `pd.unique()` instead.

Comment: this will give the wrong answer: `np.unique()` sorts the values. `pd.unique()` doesn't (keeps the insertion order, and is faster: `O[n]` instead of `O[n log n]`).

Answer (score 3):

Without `numpy`:

```py
out = list(map(dict(zip({k:0 for k in original}.keys(), modified)).get, original))

>>> out
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

### Explanation

So why does it work?

- `{k:0 for k in original}` is a way to find the distinct values in `original`, **in insertion order** (unlike `set` where order is undefined). It is a `dict` where the keys are the distinct values, and the value is always 0.
- once we have that, we take the `keys()` and zip with the `modified` values into a dict. E.g.

  ```py
  >>> dict(zip({k:0 for k in original}.keys(), modified))
  {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 8}
  ```
- we then use that as a map to replace the original values with `map(_the_mapping_dict_.get, original)`.

### Addendum: alternatives and performance

Here are a few other ways to achieve the same result, and how long they take.

```py
def pure_py(om):
    """Pure Python"""
    original, modified = om
    return list(map(dict(zip({k: 0 for k in original}.keys(), modified)).get, original))

def py_with_pd_unique(om):
    """Using a dict for replacement, but using pd.unique() to get the unique values"""
    original, modified = om
    return list(map(dict(zip(pd.unique(original), modified)).get, original))

def np_select(om):
    """Using np.select and assuming inputs are np.array"""
    original, modified = om
    return np.select([original == v for v in pd.unique(original)], modified, original)

def vect_dict_get(om):
    """Using a vectorized dict.get()"""
    original, modified = om
    d = dict(zip(pd.unique(original), modified))
    return np.apply_along_axis(np.vectorize(d.get), 0, original)
```

Then:

```py
import perfplot
from math import isqrt

def setup(n):
    original = np.random.randint(0, isqrt(n), n)
    modified = np.arange(len(pd.unique(original)))
    return original, modified

perfplot.show(
    setup=setup,
    n_range=[4 ** k for k in range(4, 11)],
    kernels=[
        pure_py,
        py_with_pd_unique,
        np_select,
        vect_dict_get,
    ],
    xlabel='len(original)',
)
```

Conclusion: `py_with_pd_unique` is the fastest through the range. For 1M elements in `original`, it is almost twice as fast as the rest:

```py
o, m = setup(1_000_000)

%timeit pure_py((o, m))
# 209 ms ± 359 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit py_with_pd_unique((o, m))
# 108 ms ± 217 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you really constrained in using `np.where`? If not, an alternative solution might be:

```py
import numpy as np
original = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3])
modified = original.copy()
d = {2: 3, 3: 8}
for k, v in d.items():
    modified[original == k] = v
print(modified)
# array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` will return a boolean index to where the condition is satisfied.

Indexing + assignment should do this:

```py
import numpy as np

original = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3])
out = np.empty(original.shape, dtype=int)
modified = [1, 3, 8]

for x, y in zip(np.unique(original), modified):
    out[np.where(original == x)] = y

print(out)
# [1 1 1 3 3 3 8 8 8 8]
```